# Installing nvm on bash on ubunutu on windows 10 throws error

Tags: linux, node.js, windows, ubuntu, nvm

I'm testing the new bash on ubuntu on windows 10 and the first thing I tried to do is to install node. Of course, since I now have a "Linux system" I went ahead and installed nvm.

I also had to

```
apt-get make gcc g++
```

One done i tried

```
nvm install v4.4.2
```

but I got:

```
make -C out BUILDTYPE=Release V=1
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/.nvm/src/node-v4.4.2/out'
g++ -pthread -rdynamic -m64 -fuse-ld=gold -B/root/.nvm/src/node-
v4.4.2/third_party/binutils/Linux_x64/Release/bin -m64  -o /root/.nvm/src/node-v4.4.2/out/Release/mksnapshot -Wl,--start-group /root/.nvm/src/node-v4.4.2/out/Release/obj.target/mksnapshot/deps/v8/src/snapshot/mksnapshot.o /root/.nvm/src/node-v4.4.2/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/libv8_base.a /root/.nvm/src/node-v4.4.2/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/libv8_nosnapshot.a /root/.nvm/src/node-v4.4.2/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/libv8_libplatform.a /root/.nvm/src/node-v4.4.2/out/Release/obj.target/deps/v8/tools/gyp/libv8_libbase.a -Wl,--end-group -ldl -lrt
/usr/bin/ld.gold: fatal error: /root/.nvm/src/node-v4.4.2/out/Release/mksnapshot: Invalid argument
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [/root/.nvm/src/node-v4.4.2/out/Release/mksnapshot] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/.nvm/src/node-v4.4.2/out'
make: *** [node] Error 2
nvm: install v4.4.2 failed!
```

Do you know what's causing this? I think that I may have something missconfigured on the make command maybe?

NOTE: installing node using the "official way" works, that is:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's an issue in the bash subsystem. There are several open issues on github.com relating to installing `nvm`, `rbenv`, `rvm`, as well as creating symlinks.

These two issues appear to be directly related to the problem you're experiencing.
https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/6
https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/9

Also, FYI, I have attempted to build node 4 and node 5 from source, but fail during the `make` command with this message:

`/usr/bin/ld.gold: fatal error: /root/working/node-v5.10.1/out/Release/mksnapshot: Invalid argument
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`